# Add Password to a File on Upload or other solution

Tags: php, mysql, security, file-upload

I don't think this is possible, but want to see if larger brains than mine can come up with an idea.

I'm managing a site that allows companies with member users to upload docs that have their customers' info on them. These files may contain sensitive info... say SSN for example. If Jan at Company ABC uploads a file, Jack at the same company should be able to access the file. We've got all this worked out fine. The issue is when they've downloaded the file to their local computers, we have no control over them. If they lose a laptop for example all the files can be compromised.

One idea I've been considering is creating a policy to require a pwd be added to all files BEFORE uploading and the pwd be entered as a field. When Jan uploads a pdf with pwd "mydogsname" this is stored in the DB so when Jack downloads he can see the pwd to open the file. If he loses his laptop, the file is still encrypted (unless extra measures were taken to save an unencrypted version)

The goals are to make it easy for people to get to their files, but to make it difficult for anyone outside of the system to be able to access the info should there be a break in the chain of possession.

Encrypting into a .zip was another idea but that would be opened once they download...

This solution relies on the users following a protocol though, which isn't enforceable from the system AFAIK.

Comment: `"This solution relies on the users following a protocol though, which isn't enforceable from the system AFAIK."` And nothing you do can stop a user from writing down a piece of information on a post-it note, or taking a picture of the screen with their phone. The users are either trusted with the data or they're not. The conundrum you're describing boils down to, "How can I give data to my users without giving them the data?" Enforcing laptop encryption is a good idea, encrypting all network communications is a good idea, etc. But educating/trusting users is not a technical problem.

Comment: Since users *will* need to see the actual, original, unencrypted file at some point, pretty much all bets are off. You may place hurdles in their way to get to that file, but once they have it they'll probably just keep it on their desktop just the same. You can't force security on security unconscious people outside your sphere of influence. You *could* produce custom browser plugins that download, decrypt and display the data without giving the user the possibility to *save* it; but that's probably not feasible, and if users want to copy the data they'll find a way (see @David).

Comment: Related anecdote: I once consulted for a company under HIPAA jurisdiction. They'd spent a high 7 figures (licensing components, development, integration, support, etc.) on a solution that would show documents to their users but disable saving/copying/screenshots/everything.  Users had no way to persist the data locally.  When they proudly demonstrated this system to me, the first thing I did was take a picture of the screen with my phone.  They were... not amused.

Comment: David: Your last comment is kind of the situation we're in. I guess I was looking to see if there was a better way to do it than what I described to at least mitigate some of the liability should there be a lawsuit. Shooting the image w/ your phone would be making a copy, which isn't my concern legally at that point, but making it more secure/difficult for files coming out of the system could be... thx for the info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in the comments, this can't be done.  Unless maybe you tie the users to a chair, confiscate their cell phones and Google Glass, remove all electronic and mechanical devices from the room, (including the computer with the data), print the data on a sheet of paper, securely shred it when finished, and use the Men In Black red flashy thingy to erase their memory.

That being said, I know this isn't what you were hoping for, but the "solution" is two part:

1. Part 1 is user education.  Create a simple training presentation (death by LibreOffice Impress) that will summarize the responsibilities of users to leave documents passworded/encrypted all the time when not in use, not send them via email, etc.
2. Have a scary sounding EULA that has to be accepted by the user before accessing any of the documents.  Point out that they are responsible for protecting the data and that they accept this responsibility.

Of course have the company legal team review the "solution" to make sure you're on good ground.

FWIW, I know many, many people who have tried to do exactly what you're trying to do.  If you do figure something out that works, you'll be a very rich man or woman.  May the force be with you.

Comment: I was thinking it's more of a policy and a "your ass is grass" scenario if they break it. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't a silver bullet I wasn't aware of. Appreciate it.